# Make nmap respond quicker to hosts that are down

Tags: ping, nmap

I’m using nmap to ping 150k IP addresses, the problem is it takes too long to check the down IPs. It’s taking less than a second to check for the IPS that are up but if any are down it slows the process down.

Is there any way to speed this up, anything at all. Thanks!

Comment: In the manpage (`man nmap`)  I see:  "--host-timeout <time>: Give up on target after this long" . Is this helpful?

Comment: In the man page (`man nmap`) search for the word `parallel`. There are a number of parallelisation options that may help for a dataset of that size

Comment: Also: "How slow is *slow*?" Even sending out 150k packets will take some time.

Comment: Use `fping` instead. Or read `man nmap` about `--max-parallelism`.